# how to create a program that generate a source code programatically and compile it and execute after successfull compilation

Tags: c#, compilation, generic-programming

How to create a program (Parent Program) that creates .cs(generate source code programatically from a Parent Program) file and compile it and execute after successfull compilation and communicate result with Parent program.

What i done is

Step 1:
i can create file using c# application using System.IO namespace

Step 2:
there is option that we can compile program by command line using "csc" from console can execute it by using Prosess.Start() in System.Globalization namespace

But the Problems are

1. how to know it's compiled properly.
2. how to communicate Parent program with generated program

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "creates .cs files".

Comment: .cs file means another c# program. why every one is vote it down. does any thing wrong in it?

Comment: That part was clear. What is unclear is what you mean by "create". Do you want to generate source code programatically? Or does the source code already exist and you just want to compile it?

Comment: want to generate source code programatically from a Parent Program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at System.Reflection.Emit - that allows you to generate MSIL assemblies at runtime. Here are two starting points:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx